# Is Expression type same as object, references, or functions type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[n4868(6.8.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#general-1) :

> [*Note [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#general-note-1)*: [[basic.types]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types) and the subclauses thereof impose requirements on implementations regarding the representation of types. There are two kinds of types: fundamental types and compound types. Types describe objects, references, or functions. — *end note*]

It said "Types describe objects, reference, or functions.", but how about Expression? There is also a label called "Type" in "Properties of expressions" in spec([n4868 7.2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.type)). Is the "Type" same as "Type" in Basic([n4868 6.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types))?

Sorry about that this is kind of a tricky question, but I'm confused about that.

Comment: I hope you are not trying to learn C++ by reading the standard

Comment: @bolov the OP can if the OP is *the one* :D

Comment: All operands of an expression have types.   All expressions give a result when evaluated, and that result has a type.   That is typically described in the standard as the type of an expression.

Comment: Note that your first quote is actually a note (you left the note markers out of the quote). Notes are not normative anyway, so it shouldn't really matter what it says and it could just be missing something in the list that should be included.

Comment: I guess the sentence from the Note is related to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.types#def:object_type, i.e. it is about kinds of types and not about what can haz type.

Comment: @user17732522 yeah I think it missed the type of value, too.

Answer (score 3):

“Expression” is a grammatical construct. The string `3+4` parses as an expression, as does `foo(bar)`. Each of those expressions, when evaluated following the rules of the language, will result in a value, which will have a type. Informally one could call that the type of the expression itself, and I believe the standard does just that. But there’s no `Expression` type.

Comment: "_Each of those expressions, when evaluated following the rules of the language, will result in an object_": I don't think that is correct. Specifically a prvalue expression is not referring to an object until prvalue-to-xvalue (temporary materialization) conversion is applied. Yet a prvalue expression still has a type. Also, a lvalue expression can refer to an object with a type different from the type of the lvalue expression, which this doesn't seem to capture either.

Comment: Yes, I should have said “value” rather than “object”.

Comment: This brings it back to the issue OP is describing though: "_Types describe objects, references, or functions._" It doesn't list values.

Comment: yeah that's the point I confused, expression may result in an value, but the spec didn't list values.

Answer (score 3):

In C++,

> the type of an expression is never a reference.

Lets discuss this with the following snippet:

```
int i = 0; //i is of type int
int &refI = i; 
int &&ref = 3;
```

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
int i = 0;
```

In the above statement, the variable `i` is an lvalue(which is a *value category* of expressions) of **type** `int`.

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement:

```
int &refI = i;
```

In the above statement, `refI` has ***lvalue reference type***. But note that when used as/in an expression, the expression `refI` is an **lvalue** of the type that this reference refers to(which is nothing but `int` here).

That is, for a *reference variable*<sup>1</sup> `refI`, the expression `refI` has the **referenced type**.

##### Case 3

Here we consider the statement:

```
int &&ref = 3;
```

In the above statement, `ref` has ***rvalue reference type***. Again when used as/in an expression, the expression `ref` is an **lvalue** of the type that this reference refers to(which is `int`).

Thus we again see that for a *reference variable*<sup>1</sup> `ref`, the expression `ref` has the **referenced type**.

---

> Is the "Type" same as "Type" in Basic(n4868 6.8)? It said "Types describe objects, reference, or functions.", but how about Expression?

Type has the same meaning. The above example snippet and explanation should clarify the expression part that you're asking.

---

##### Summary

Say we have a reference variable `r` that has either an ***lvalue reference type*** or an ***rvalue reference type***. Then **regardless**, the expression `r` will always be an ***lvalue*** of the type that the reference refers to.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that a reference is not an object by itself. Instead a reference refers to some other object.</sup>